# CVS check-out works hard-coded but not with variables

Tags: shell, cygwin, cvs

I am using cygwin to call an .sh with the following line:

```
    echo cvs co -d"$tmpdir" -r"$revision" "$cvsdir/$file"
    cvs co -d"$tmpdir" -r"$revision" "$cvsdir/$file"
```

The echo prints:

```
    cvs co -dtmp -r1.2 my_module/interfaces/my_file.sql
```

And the error:

```
    cvs server: cannot find module  `my_module/interfaces/my_file.sql' 
    -ignored cvs [checkout aborted]: cannot expand modules
```

The funny thing is that if I use

```
    cvs co -dtmp -r1.2 'my_module/interfaces/my_file.sql'
         or
    cvs co -dtmp -r1.2 my_module/interfaces/my_file.sql
```

Instead of:

```
    cvs co -d"$tmpdir" -r"$revision" "$cvsdir/$file"
```

It works (checks out succesfully). Do you guys have any idea, why that happens?

The module's path output by the echo is exactly the same as the one I hard-coded plus single quotes. I tried doing something like:

```
    cvs co -d"$tmpdir" -r"$revision" "'$cvsdir/$file'"
```

But the module still wasn't found.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried this:

```
    echo cvs co -d"$tmpdir" -r"$revision" "$cvsdir/$file" > .cvs_cmd
    cat .cvs_cmd
    source .cvs_cmd
    rm -f .cvs_cmd
```

Comment: It didn't solve, but lead to a clue of what is going on. There are CR and LF characters where they shouldn't be. I tried removing then, still it didn't work. Thing is .cvs_cmd appears with a CR but I am pretty sure the variables in question have not LF or CR. (I checked the source).

Comment: I can't duplicate your condition: no CR is found on .cvs_cmd. How did you set these variables (tmp, tmpdir, ...), do you set them on the script? or external environment variable? How do you execute this script? by "." or "source" or something else?

Answer (score 0):

When you checkout from a CVS repository, the server looks for modules, e.g.

```
cvs checkout module1 module2
```

The module names are defined in a file named [`CVSROOT/modules`](https://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/cvs_21.html#SEC135). To add a new module, you modify this `modules` file, e.g. you checkout CVSROOT

```
cvs checkout CVSROOT
```

add another line to `CVSROOT/modules`

```
mymodule -a relative/path/to/interfaces
```

and commit the changes

```
cvs commit -m 'Added mymodule' CVSROOT/modules
```